# Intellij: SDK 17 is not compatible with the source version 17

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, build, configuration

I am trying to get a project to build in IntelliJ but I keep getting an error. I have tried different JDKs such as the jet brains and OpenJDK but I always get this error

[image]

Everything I have seems to be pointing to java 17 so I feel a bit confused

pom.xml

[image]

Project Structure

[image]
[image]
[image]

Java compiler settings

[image]

Maven Runner Settings

[image]

I feel like it could have to do with my project layout?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` values are wrong.

Replace `1.17` and set it instead to `17` per [JEP 223](https://openjdk.org/jeps/223).

```
<maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
```

Comment: This I think solved the above issue but now I get another error:
"package junit.framework does not exist"

I'm not sure if this is part of the same issue so I have updated my question

Comment: that's for sure another issue

Comment: maybe open another question with the content in your pom (dependencies section) so people can check and help you? -- also, if this specific issue was solved, maybe you should mark the question as 'solved'

Comment: Thank you, will remove the edit and do this

Comment: Tip to the reader: With later versions of Maven etc. you can reduce those two lines to one: `<maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>`

Comment: @BasilBourque This configuration has nothing to do with Maven .. it's for the [maven-compiler-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) which supports that since Maven Compiler Plugin Version 3.6